# Cannot change sysdba password with Gsec

Tags: firebird, firebird1.5

I have firebird 1.5 super server installed on my windows 7 machine.

I am unable to use the Gsec utility to change the sysdba password for the default user.

The firebird service is running and I verified this several times.

When running gsec from a command prompt i receive this error
**unavailable database, unable to open database**

The command i am using is the following `gsec -user sysdba -pass masterkey -mo sysdba -pw whatever`

Using a gui admin tool, i am able to change the password without issue and it apears to only be an issue when I try to run gsec directly.

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Why you still use Firebird 1.5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My NEW advice is to upgrade to firebird 2.1.4. I was able to solve my problem by running the firebird guardian as administrator. The following GSEC command then works:
gsec -database "localhost:E:\tools\firebird2\security2.fdb" -user sysdba -pass masterkey -mo sysdba -pw newpass

My firebird is installed in E:\tools\firebird2 and newpass is the new passowrd.

Maybe running the guardian as administrator will work for 1.5 also.

So Uncle Bill is back in my good books, but I'll never forgive him for the evil that is the "windows registry" :-)

Answer (score 2):

The only advice I can give you is don't update to firebird version 2. It has the same problem.
Unless Hugues Van Landeghem has solved it :-)
I get:
cannot attach to password database
unable to open database
I suspect it is caused by Windows 7 "clever" security, but I always blame poor MS.
I guess their OS is not as backward compatible as it used to be.

Answer (score 2):

On a 64-bit Windows 7, the 'user name and password not defined' error was solved after installing the 64-bit Firebird instead of the 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Firebird Guardian as administrator.